# Execute multiple queries in parallel via Streams

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I am having the following method:

```
public String getResult() {

        List<String> serversList = getServerListFromDB();

        List<String> appList = getAppListFromDB();

        List<String> userList = getUserFromDB();

        return getResult(serversList, appList, userList);
    }
```

Here I am calling three method sequentially which in turns hits the DB and fetch me results, then I do post processing on the results I got from the DB hits. I know how to call these three methods concurrently via use of `Threads`. But I would like to use Java 8 `Parallel Stream` to achieve this. Can someone please guide me how to achieve the same via Parallel Streams?

**EDIT** I just want to call the methods in parallel via Stream.

```
private void getInformation() {
    method1();
    method2();
    method3();
    method4();
    method5();
}
```

Comment: what do you expect the end result to be? whats your final String?

Comment: I just want to call the above three methods concurrently. Its just an example.

Comment: Your last edit makes question more confusing...

Comment: You would probably save more time with performance-correct database code, like not opening a completely separate connection and transaction for each query.

Comment: Sometimes it's not possible if you need to access children tables. For example I have a query with about 10 children tables and trying to make that into one massive join is much slower than multiple simple select statements. And the code is much more manageable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You may utilize `CompletableFuture` this way:

```
public String getResult() {

    // Create Stream of tasks:
    Stream<Supplier<List<String>>> tasks = Stream.of(
            () -> getServerListFromDB(),
            () -> getAppListFromDB(),
            () -> getUserFromDB());

    List<List<String>> lists = tasks
         // Supply all the tasks for execution and collect CompletableFutures
         .map(CompletableFuture::supplyAsync).collect(Collectors.toList())
         // Join all the CompletableFutures to gather the results
         .stream()
         .map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Use the results. They are guaranteed to be ordered in the same way as the tasks
    return getResult(lists.get(0), lists.get(1), lists.get(2));
}
```

Comment: would this open 3 new threads, one for each Supplier? if answer is yes, willd each thread open a new database connection? Thx

Comment: This solution just works for me. Excellent. But I didn't understand this part `.map(CompletableFuture::supplyAsync)
.collect(Collectors.toList())        
         .stream()
         .map(CompletableFuture::join)` Why you collect as list then again stream then map ? BTW I remove those two collect and stream part then the things didn't work. Could you please explain a bit ?

Comment: This has worked like magic.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, a standard parallel stream is probably not the best fit for your use case. I would complete each task asynchronously using an ExecutorService and "join" them when calling the getResult method:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

Future<List<String>> serversList = es.submit(() -> getServerListFromDB());
Future<List<String>> appList = es.submit(() -> getAppListFromDB());
Future<List<String>> userList = es.submit(() -> getUserFromDB());

return getResult(serversList.get(), appList.get(), userList.get());
```

Comment: But `CompletableFuture` is not better that the pre-Java 8 usage: `Future<List<String>> appList = es.submit(() -> getAppListFromDB());`.

Comment: @Holger hum - looks like I got carried away indeed.

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` is what used for `side-effects`, you can call `foreach` on a `parallel stream`. ex:

```
listOfTasks.parallelStream().foreach(list->{
  submitToDb(list);
});
```

However, `parallelStream` uses the common `ForkJoinPool` which is arguably not good for `IO-bound` tasks.

Consider using a `CompletableFuture` and supply an appropriate `ExecutorService`. It gives more flexibility (`continuation`,configuration). For ex:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
List<CompletableFuture> allFutures = new ArrayList<>();
for(Query query:queries){
 CompletableFuture<String> query = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        // submit query to db
        return result;
  }, executorService);
  allFutures.add(query);
}

 CompletableFuture<Void> all = CompletableFuture.allOf(allFutures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[allFutures.size()]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite clear what do you mean, but if you just want to run some process on these lists on parallel you can do something like this:

```
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("1", "234", "33");

    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "cddd");

    List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList("1331", "22", "33");

    List<List<String>> listOfList = Arrays.asList(list1, list2, list3);

    listOfList.parallelStream().forEach(list -> System.out.println(list.stream().max((o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length()))));
```

(it will print most lengthy elements from each list).

Comment: `Collections.max(list, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))` or using `import static`: `max(list, comparingInt(String::length))`…

Comment: @Holger this is just an example of paralleling some process without claim of `max...length` issue decision

Comment: `parallelStream`(uses the fork join pool underline) doesn't perform well with the I/O bound task whatsoever.