# Java 8 - parallel streams cause Jira's SearchService.search query to produce empty result list

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, jira, java-stream

I want to process a list in parallel using stream but just adding parallel to the stream produces inconsistent results but running as a normal stream produces the correct results. Each item in the list is fully independent of the others and can be processed in different threads. After way too much debugging, I feel its a threading issue. Inside this `tokenizerIssue()`. it will pull data from various fields within the Issue object. some of these fields end up being a 3rd party (Jira JQL) query to a database. For what ever reason this query call returns mostly empty list under parallel operations but perfectly fine under normal single threaded streams. I say mostly because about 5% of the time it will have the correct result.

So i'm hoping to find a way around this bug if possible. I was thinking i could convert my streams syntax to another but cant figure out how that will work. 
here is my code

```
List<Object[][]> list = issues
            .stream()
            .map(issue -> tokenizeIssue(hasHeaders, issue, fieldNames))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

the `tokenizeIssue()` method is fairly CPU intensive and is the reason i want to run it in parallel. I need a safer way to parallel stream this rather than swapping .stream() with .parallel()

current thoughts are converting it to the form of

```
Stream<Supplier<List<Issue>>> tasks = Stream.of(() -> issues);  
tasks.map(CompletableFuture::supplyAsync).collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and return `List<Object[][]>` but i couldn't figure out how to make it work. Another thought i had was to use `Collectors.groupingByConcurrent(classifier, downstream)` somehow.

Any other thoughts will help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should investigate why “just adding parallel to the stream produces inconsistent results”, as these problems are unlikely to disappear when using a different concurrency framework. Further, your last code fragment makes no sense at all. The `issues` variable already exist and its repeated wrapping and unwrapping does not add any benefit to it.

Comment: @Holger I did investigate why adding parallel gave inconsistent results as i briefly mentioned in the last section of my first paragraph. I did not explain why I thought it was a threading issue. From what i can tell, Jira seems to expects querys to run in the same thread for caching purposes. The best topic i could find relating to the issue is [here](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/73389/why-searchservice-search-returns-an-empty-set-of-issues-when-issue-navigator-found-correct-number).

Comment: @Holger The code fragment you are referring to is incomplete and is what i need help modifying to get the same results as my first code fragment. the issues variable is just the list i want to stream as I'm doing in the first code fragment. Yes maybe it wont work but it was something i wanted to try. I was pulling this idea from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33649902/execute-multiple-queries-in-parallel-via-streams)

Comment: It’s totally unclear what your question is about. If your method `tokenizeIssue` is not thread safe, you *must not* call it from different threads. So why are you trying to find a convoluted way to do what the first code example does? Why don’t you simply use the sequential stream code, if you already know, that multi-threading is not an option?

Comment: Why don't you pull all the required data within the same thread? That way you reduce time querying the db, and then you can parallelize other operations.