# CompletableFuture not working as accepted with certain java 8 stream code

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I am following [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33650607/1743867)

The following code snippet work just fine. Use the all thread

## Snippet 1

```
scrolledPage.stream()
    .filter(this::isUserDoesntHaveId)
    .map(this::processSingle)                                          // processSingle method return supplier
    .map(task -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, executorService)) // map to CompletableFuture
    .collect(Collectors.toList())                                      // Collect those as list
    .stream()                                                          // then again making another stream out of that.
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have confusion on this segment of code

```
    .map(task -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, executorService)) // map to CompletableFuture
    .collect(Collectors.toList())                                      // Collect those as list
    .stream()                                                          // then again making another stream out of that.
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
```

Why I need collect and then again make stream of it. I have tested with as bellow.

## Snippet 2

```
scrolledPage.stream()
    .filter(this::isUserDoesntHaveId)
    .map(this::processSingle)                                           // processSingle method return supplier
    .map(task -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, executorService)) // map to CompletableFuture
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)               // this code is similar without the collecting part.
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With the code I have seen the last code snippet is using only one thread in thread pool. But the first one uses every thread. What is the differences between this two code snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first snippet can be broken into two parts.
In the first part, where you are submitting all your tasks to the async process using `CompletableFuture` and as it immediately returns `Future` object, the stream will process and collect all future in list.

```
List<Future> futures = scrolledPage.stream()
    ...
    .map(task -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, executorService))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

And later part, stream processing will wait for results as you are using `join` but by then all thread would be at work. Hence it is able to utilize all threads.

```
    futures.stream()
       .map(CompletableFuture::join)
       ...
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Streams do lazy evaluations means it will process elements only when required. (requirement is triggered by terminal operations, in this case `collect`).

In the second snippet, `map(CompletableFuture::join)` make thread to wait for the result before processing the next element in the stream

```
.stream()
...
.map(task -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, executorService))
.map(CompletableFuture::join)
...
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Hence, your task (next element) in the stream would be processed only when the first task is completed. That will make your tasks to be executed in sequential order one after another.

Comment: In the second snippet, isn't this `map(task -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(task, executorService))` submit all the task and map to future and send to down stream for the join? Actually I didn't understand this line of yours. `make thread to wait for the result before processing the next element in the stream.`

Comment: @seal it won't submit all tasks instead it will submit one by one in the first snippet also. streams trigger evaluation as lazy. For Example, let's say you terminal operation is to find first, there is no need to process other elements. As your join method waits for the result in an intermediate step, processing becomes sequential.

Comment: you can check on stream operations like terminal / intermediate operations here. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html